# Create charts using Qt in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, charts, qt5

I am trying to create a line chart in Visual Studio 2015 by using Qt 5.9.

I already set up the .pro file, but still get a problem with QtLib.

In **main.cpp**
[image: main.cpp]

In .pro file

[image: .pro]

**The error messages**:
[image]

I appreciate any help from all of you.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed that module? This module does not come by default, try to run the installer again and activate it.

Comment: Make sure you regenerate visual studio solution after you add the QT += charts in the pro file.